# FREETEXTTABLE Alternative

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We're looking to move a database from a local SQL 2008 server to SQL Azure however we use `FREETEXTSEARCH` which is currently unsupported. Is there an alternative to `FREETEXTSEARCH` that we could use that is supported on AZURE, and/or can you write a custom function that does the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a look at [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/). It is great free text search engine. There is a Azure version available. It powers the search on StackExchange network. [Lucene on Azure](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Library-for-83562538).

Answer (score 0):

You can use FULLTEXT search Azure SQL just doesn't provide you an interface to create full indexes, you'll have to create them via script.